# ExtJs 5.1 - set, update and refresh html-config of Ext.ux.IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, extjs5, vis.js

I have prepared a [Sencha-Fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) for my problem, which can be stated as follows:

**(1) Why is the** `Ext.ux.IFrame` **named** `panel_iframe` **not showing** *ASDFG* **which is inside the passed** `html` **config** `<html><body>ASDFG</body></html>`?

The [Sencha docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame) on `Ext.ux.IFrame` tell me, that such a property exsists. I need to assemble the html dynamically so going with the `src` config is no option for me, since the client is not allowed to change files on the server.

Just in case the Fiddle is not working:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'myfiddleexample',

    launch : function() {

        var panel_iframe = Ext.create('Ext.ux.IFrame', {
            //src: 'some/path/some/file.html' /*i know this works*/
            html: '<html><body>ASDFG</body></html>' /*why does this not work?*/
        });

        var panel   = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            frame:true,
            title: 'panel_5',
            padding: '1 1 1 1',
            margin: '1 1 1 1',
            layout: 'fit',
            //html: '<html><body>ASDFG</body></html>'  /*i know this works, too*/
            items: [panel_iframe]
        });

        var vp = new Ext.Viewport({
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [panel],
            autoScroll: true,
            renderTo : Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

**Another question (2):**
I wanted to use the `IFrame` named `panel_iframe` in order to put some [vis.js graph network visualisations](http://visjs.org/network_examples.html) in it.`
Is there an alternative approach to this?

**Yet another question (3):**
Has someone combined **ExtJs** with **vis.js** and can provide a SenchaFiddle, which inits a [simple graph](http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html) inside a `Ext.ux.IFrame` or any other `Ext.Component` like for example `Ext.panel.Panel`?

Comment: The link to your fiddle is incorrect. Did you get any errors in console? Did you include the 'ux' package?